# cant seam to get a full screen listview on a tv screen

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, size

hi guys my listview seams to get a boarder on the left and right edge. this only happens on xl devices such as tv screens. i had the same problem with my webview a few weeks ago and remember using a setting for wideviewport. is there a way of doing the same sort of thing but for a list view?

```
 <ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lvDownloadbuttons"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar"
    android:splitMotionEvents="true"
    />
```

Ive tried adding this line to my xml code but does nothing.
      android:fillViewport="true"

also tried adding 
      android:layout_weight = "1"
[image: screenshot of my problem]

Comment: Seems like parent of listview have some kind of padding. Generate xml for xl screen and post it.

Comment: the parent has no padding. its just a linear layout set to vertical

Comment: you were actually right even though the padding was set to zero it still had it there thanks @user6657161